# Show Navigation Bar Segue

Tags: ios, swift, modal-dialog, storyboard

I'm trying to show the navigation bar from the navigation controller in Swift. I'm linking to a view through a segue from a modal view. For some reason, the navigation isn't showing in the view. How do I achieve this? The sidebar view controller is presented modally from the root view controller. I've posted a screenshot of my storyboard below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am confused as to what your UI stack looks like. I am not seeing your UINavigationController. Can your clarify your stack more.

What is presenting your My Profile view control and then what presents your Side Bar View Controller? Where are you expecting to see a navigation bar?

Comment: I'll update the question with a complete view of the storyboard.

Comment: So are you seeing the navigation controller on the screen titled "Back and Forths"? What is the flow that you are expecting to see the navigation?

Comment: Yes, the navigation controller works as expected in that view. I'm wondering how to make the navigation controller appear in the profile view.

Comment: Any possible solutions?

Comment: Sanne gave good response. When you show a view as a modal, it will NOT have a navigation bar. You are showing something about the navigation stack. You can drag a UINavigationBar to your modal view and have it on screen. You could add a UIBarButton and have that as close on your UINavigationBar. If you want to use the back functionality of the UINavigationController, you have to push your view controller onto the stack instead of showing it modally.

Answer (score 0):

When you segue to a UIViewController model it will not take the UINavigationController with it. If you want a navigation bar there you should add it to that view, but then you should think about why you present that view modal and not just push it on the stack?

When you push the viewcontroller on the stack it will take the navigation bar. When you want this behaviour you should choose the "Show" segue.